# drug pairs classification using lstm and cnn

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, classification, lstm

I need some help for a classification problem.
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.
So, the dataset is in the form of Drug pairs, and we have the embedding_df of every drug generated using RDF2vec model and the classes (0 /1 whether there is an interaction or not).
How is it possible to do the classification part using the Conv-LSTM model? How should the train and y_train should be?
Here is the full GitHub code but the Conv-LSTM functionality was not added. https://github.com/rezacsedu/Drug-Drug-Interaction-Prediction/blob/master/Sample_DDI_Prediction_RDF2Vec.ipynb

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

```
def Conv_LSTM(num_classes, timesteps, reg):
input_layer = Input(shape=(1, 300))

conv1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same')(bn1)

conv2 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
bn2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same')(bn2)

conv3 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
bn3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)

# Global Layers
gmaxpl = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(bn3)
gmeanpl = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(bn3)
mergedlayer = concatenate([gmaxpl, gmeanpl], axis=1)

fl = Flatten()(mergedlayer)
rv = RepeatVector(300)(mergedlayer)
lstm1 = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(bn3)
do3 = Dropout(0.5)(lstm1)

lstm2 = LSTM(64)(do3)
do4 = Dropout(0.2)(lstm2)

flat = Flatten()(mergedlayer)
output_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(mergedlayer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)  

return model


def model_train(model, number_epoch, train_x, train_y):   
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

# a stopping function should the validation loss stop improving
#earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='auto')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=optimizer)
#plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='ConvLSTM.png')   
tensorboardRNN = TensorBoard(log_dir="RNN_logs/{}".format(time()))

#for i in range(number_epoch):
history1 = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[tensorboardRNN], batch_size=32, class_weight = sample_weights, epochs=int(number_epoch), shuffle=False)
#model.reset_states()        

print(model.summary())

return model, history1
```

---

### we have the drug drug interaaction (pairs) list and the embedding
the question how should the input to the model be (train_x,train_y)?

Calling the model now

```
reg = L1L2(l1 = 0.01, l2 = 0.01)
model = ml.Conv_LSTM(num_classes = 2, timesteps = 8, reg = reg)
model.summary()
convLSTM = ml.model_train(model, number_epoch = 20,train_x,train_y)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it is on the github repo

Comment: Ive edited the question , is it more clear now ?